# awk print all matching lines including duplicates

Tags: text-processing, awk

How can I print all matching lines between two files including the duplicates

sourcefile:

```
SNP value
RS1 0.55
RS2 0.52
RS3 0.25
RS4 0.22
```

queryfile:

```
SNP
RS1
RS2
RS2
RS3
RS4
RS4
```

Desired output:

```
SNP value
RS1 0.55
RS2 0.52
RS2 0.52
RS3 0.25
RS4 0.22
RS4 0.22
```

At present I am using the following command to retrieve the matching lines but is removing the duplicates, while i need to print all lines including the duplicates,

Any suggestions please

Thanks

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}a[$1]{print}' queryfile sourcefile > output
```

Answer (score 2):

The `join` command will join these two files together for you

```
join sourcefile queryfile
```

Output (from your example files)

```
SNP value
RS1 0.55
RS2 0.52
RS2 0.52
RS3 0.25
RS4 0.22
RS4 0.22
```

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially just a matter of processing the files in the opposite order

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} a[$1]{print a[$1]}' sourcefile queryfile
SNP value
RS1 0.55
RS2 0.52
RS2 0.52
RS3 0.25
RS4 0.22
RS4 0.22
```